Alexa - Cancel regular weather notifications without the app
My sister who is registered blind, relies on her Amazon echo for many things. Recently she asked for a weather forecast and Alexa asked if she would like a regular weather update. She said yes but was not asked for when. She now receives a notification every morning at 7 am which happens to be the time she was asked but was not the time she wanted.
On trying to cancel this, she is told to use the Alexa App. Because of her lack of sight, she cannot do this. I live far away and cannot help.
Question
Is there some way that I can remotely use the Amazon Alexa app to stop these intrusive notifications or is there a way that she can do so verbally?

the Alexa app is on a device that can be situated anywhere in the world

Try “Alexa, disable the weather forecast routine.”  That might work

She can add you to the "Household Profiles", but it is in the app.

Open the Alexa app on your phone.
Tap the More tab at the bottom.
Select Settings and choose Household Profile. An overview of Amazon Household displays.
Tap Start.
Invite a family member to share your Echo. They must accept the invitation to join your household.

More tips can be found here:
https://www.androidpolice.com/enable-amazon-echo-multiple-users/

Thanks for your reply. I'll look into it but it looks like that works when we live in the same household and want Alexa to recognise different voices. As I said, I live in a different part of the country from my sister and can't visit just to fix her Alexa account. Am I misunderstanding your answer?

You got the answer correctly and what I indicate is that it needs to be done from the app and the solution to do it remotely doesn't exists. And this is an common problem when trying to assist remotely. I have the same challenges with assisting elderly and people with other challenges.
